# RegEx : what does @ means before (?

Tags: regex, javascript

I discovered a strange behavior in my app with regular expression and @ character followed with (.

Here are two examples of my .Net JScript adapted language :

```
//Using .Net Regex class
echo(Regex.IsMatch(".DOMAIN.S", "^\\.DOMAIN\\.S(\\.\\w*|\\b)"));//True
echo(Regex.IsMatch(".DOMAIN.@", "^\\.DOMAIN\\.@(\\.\\w*|\\b)"));//False !!

//Using JScript syntax
var re = /^\.DOMAIN\.S(\.\w*|\b)/g;
echo(re.exec(".DOMAIN.S") != null); //Ok
re = /^\.DOMAIN\.@(\.\w*|\b)/g;
echo(re.exec(".DOMAIN.@") != null); //Null !!
```

Removing (.\w*|\b) makes the test ok. So I interpret that @ followed with a ( has a special meaning in regular expression.

1. What's the meaning of it ?

2. What should be the good expression ?

Thanks very much.

ED

Comment: For your second point, could you clarify what are your intents? Give example on what you want to match and what you don't want to match.

Answer (score 3):

`Regex.IsMatch(".DOMAIN.@", "^\\.DOMAIN\\.@(\\.\\w*|\\b)")` is returning false because `^\\.DOMAIN\\.@` is matching the entire string, and then you are looking for a period and word characters, which there are none, or a word boundary. According to [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions
>   that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the    string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the    string, if the last character is a
>     word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,    where one is a word
>     character and the    other is not a
>     word character.

The at symbol is not a word character, so the second bullet is false.

So, to actually answer your question, the at symbol is not special in Regex.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `@` that's causing you problems, it's the `\b`.

`\b` matches a word boundary: there is one at the end of `".DOMAIN.S"` while there isn't one at the end of `".DOMAIN.@"`. This explains why you get a match in the first case but not the second.

Comment: thanks every body ! reg exp are logical but quite strange for me.. I've learned something, that's nice.